# Как отключить предпросмотр ссылок в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота в телеграмме на aiogram. В некоторых сообщениях, которые отправляет бот, есть ссылки. Как отключить предпросмотр ссылок?

Answer (score 5):

Передавайте параметр `disable_webpage_preview=True`. Например, отправка сообщения:

```py
await bot.send_message(chat_id=123, text="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/", disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

2.25.1 `disable_web_page_preview=True`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]